# How to iterate values inside dictionary of lists in PYTHON

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a complicated method that needs to work correctly, that I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't.

I have a dictionary as it follows:

`{'view': ['premium_subscribers', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['admins', 'normal_content', 'premium_content']}`

I need to know how to iterate one by one through each specific key values, which are arrays. For example:

```
key = delete

for loop (that iterates 1 by 1 through key "delete's" values
     
     takes "admins" value and does some processing

     in the next iteration takes normal_content and does same processing

     and so on ......
 
     its basically checking for a match to be found.
```

In case if you're interested in my method, I have it below. It has 3 dictionaries and is comparing their key's values to accomplish access permission.

If the for loop iterates correctly through each value of that key, it will start working as expected.

```
def accessPermission(operation, user, object):

domains = dict()
types = dict()
access = dict()

    access = json.load(open("access.txt"))
    domains = json.load(open("domains.txt"))
    types = json.load(open("types.txt"))

    print(types)
    print(access)
    print(domains)

    if operation in access.keys():
        firstkeyvalue = access.get(operation)[0]
        if firstkeyvalue in domains.keys():
            if user in domains.get(firstkeyvalue):
                for access.get(operation)[0] in access:
                    if object in types.values():
                        print("Success")
                else:
                    print("Error: access denied")
            else:
                print("Error: access denied")
        else:
            print("Error: access denied")
    else:
        print("Error: access denied")
```

Comment: It’s a `for` loop - `for listentry in [‘a’,’b’,’c’]:` or `for listentry in mydict[‘delete’]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you only need to iterate through the elements like this:

```
dict = {'view': ['premium_subscribers', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['admins', 'normal_content', 'premium_content']}

key = 'delete' #set somewhere
for v in dict[key]:
  print(v)
  #do what you need with that
```

Output:

```
admins
normal_content
premium_content
```

Answer (score 1):

Each Value is a `list`, so you need an extra `loop` for iterating  over the items of each list:

```
data_dict = {'view': ['premium_subscribers', 'premium_content'], 'delete': ['admins', 'normal_content', 'premium_content']}

for key in data_dict:
    
    values = data_dict[key]
    # iterate over list of values
    for v in values:
        
        # Now you have access to each one
        print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
premium_subscribers
premium_content
admins
normal_content
premium_content
```